# Warning MSB3290: wrapper assembly failure

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dll, window

Hello I am using visual studio community 2019 and I encountered a problem using the C# library  System.Windows.Forms. I tried adding the project reference but it displayed this warning:

**Warning   MSB3290 Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library "{215d64d2-031c-33c7-96e3-61794cd1ee61}". Type library 'System_Windows_Forms' was exported from a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as a CLR assembly.**

thank you

**Edit:** I re-installed all the NuGet Packages and the problem was solved

Comment: If you delete the reference, do you still have access to the namespace? (And: why is this tagged "WPF" if you want to use System.Windows.Forms?)

Comment: No even with the reference I don't have access to the name space.

Comment: On what framework is that? .NET Core 3.x, 2.x ... ?

Comment: it is on .NET Core 3.6

Comment: Which template did you use to create the project? And how did you add the reference? Did you use nuget?

Comment: Yes I used Syncfusion.Presentation, System.Drawing.Common and System.Security.Principal.Windows as NuGets. But I did use Windows Forms App (.NET Core) Template

Comment: Hm, strange. I thought the template would include the necessary winforms references.

Comment: I found this on the internet, is it related?
http://opclabs.doc-that.com/files/onlinedocs/QuickOpc/Latest/User's%20Guide%20and%20Reference-QuickOPC/Importing%20Type%20Libraries%20in%20Visual%20C++.html

Comment: Can you create a second "dummy" winforms project with that template to confirm that a reference is missing?

Comment: That article is about C++. I strongly doubt it is related.

Comment: I created a new template and it is not missing somehow...

Comment: Is there a missing dll or something alike?

Comment: Ok, so the dummy project was created just fine. Now, one-by-one add the nugets you added in the original project and see when it starts to fail. Maybe one is messing up dependencies.

Comment: I added all the NuGets one by one and then all at once and there was no problem with them.